# How to specify a generated model class, from django-simple-history, as a sender for a signal?

Tags: python, django, django-signals, django-simple-history

I would like to listen for `pre_create_historical_record` signal provided by simple-history package but only from certain sender. The problem is that historical models are generated by simple-history and I can't figure out how can I import class "core.HistoricalUser" as a type to set as sender.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get to the model class by going through the history manager as documented [here](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/common_issues.html#pointing-to-the-model).

In your specific case something like – assuming your history manager is called `history` and the model you are tracking history for is `User`:

```
pre_create_historical_record.connect(
    signal_receiver_function, 
    sender=User.history.model
)
```